PHP File Not Receiving GET Values From URL When Using Pretty (User Friendly) Names
I built my website and set it up to use SEO friendly names.  When I uploaded it to my server and did a test, the SEO friendly names works, but the value passed through the URL is not being received by my PHP file.  To be clear, this is what I am trying to do:
www.mywebsite.com/service.php?service=service-title.
What I want to do is the following:
www.mywebsite.com/service/service-title (where service is service.php and service-title is the value I want to pass through the URL).
But for some reason, the service.php is not receiving the value. I echoed the value from the $_GET["service"] variable and it outputted NULL.  I checked the error logs on Apache and it said that the service variable is undefined.
The following code I have in my htacces file:
RewriteRule ^/?service/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+) service.php?service=$1 [L,NC,NE]

The above htaccess rule works on my local machine but not on my AWS Ubuntu server.
I don't know if the problem is the htaccess file or if the problem is somewhere else.
I am using AWS Ubuntu server 22.04.5 LTS, Apache 2.4, and PHP 8.1
Also, I noticed that when I removed the htaccess file from the server, the SEO friendly names such as www.mywebsite.com/about/ (which leads to about.php) works.  I am curious to know why this page works without an htaccess file.
I tried searching everywhere and got nothing.
Please help me solve this problem.

"When I uploaded it to my server and did a test, the SEO friendly names works, but the value passed through the URL is not being received by my PHP file" - so it didn't work then?

Unrelated to your problem, but since you are at the building stage still (since it is not working), take this time to bring it up to the most recent PHP, which is 8.4 at the time of this writing.

Is it really working locally?  That should not work at all, as RewriteRule will not match the query string.  From the docs: "The Pattern will not be matched against the query string. Instead, you must use a RewriteCond with the %{QUERY_STRING} variable.".  Here's an example on how to do that.

@Don'tPanic the pattern isn't trying to match the query string. The question mark just makes the preceding slash optional (which would make the pattern work both in the server config files, as well as in .htaccess.)

"I am curious to know why this page works without an htaccess file." - that would likely be the Multiviews option at work. And it is probably also the reason /service/service-title worked to invoke your service.php, but without passing any query string parameter. So, your actual rewriting attempt did not work at all on this server. Maybe you need to add an explicit RewriteEngine On; if that doesn't change anything, then check with your server admin / hosting documentation.
